# Bootstrap Print Pdf

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, pdf, printing, col

I am Trying To Print The layout,The Layout design is below:**

For Example:

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-6">Hi</div>
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-6">Css</div>

    </div>
<div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-6">Hi</div>
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-6">Css</div>

    </div>
<div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-6">Hi</div>
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-6">Css</div>

    </div>
</div>
```

And My Print.CSS StyleSheet Is below:

```
@media print {
  .col-sm-1, .col-sm-2, .col-sm-3, .col-sm-4, .col-sm-5, .col-sm-6, .col-sm-7, .col-sm-8, .col-sm-9, .col-sm-10, .col-sm-11, .col-sm-12 {
    float: left;
  }
  .col-sm-12 {
    width: 100%;
  }
  .col-sm-11 {
    width: 91.66666667%;
  }
  .col-sm-10 {
    width: 83.33333333%;
  }
  .col-sm-9 {
    width: 75%;
  }
  .col-sm-8 {
    width: 66.66666667%;
  }
  .col-sm-7 {
    width: 58.33333333%;
  }
  .col-sm-6 {
    width: 50%;
  }
  .col-sm-5 {
    width: 41.66666667%;
  }
  .col-sm-4 {
    width: 33.33333333%;
  }
  .col-sm-3 {
    width: 25%;
  }
  .col-sm-2 {
    width: 16.66666667%;
  }
  .col-sm-1 {
    width: 8.33333333%;
  }
  .col-sm-pull-12 {
    right: 100%;
  }
  .col-sm-pull-11 {
    right: 91.66666667%;
  }
  .col-sm-pull-10 {
    right: 83.33333333%;
  }
  .col-sm-pull-9 {
    right: 75%;
  }
  .col-sm-pull-8 {
    right: 66.66666667%;
  }
  .col-sm-pull-7 {
    right: 58.33333333%;
  }
  .col-sm-pull-6 {
    right: 50%;
  }
  .col-sm-pull-5 {
    right: 41.66666667%;
  }
  .col-sm-pull-4 {
    right: 33.33333333%;
  }
  .col-sm-pull-3 {
    right: 25%;
  }
  .col-sm-pull-2 {
    right: 16.66666667%;
  }
  .col-sm-pull-1 {
    right: 8.33333333%;
  }
  .col-sm-pull-0 {
    right: auto;
  }
  .col-sm-push-12 {
    left: 100%;
  }
  .col-sm-push-11 {
    left: 91.66666667%;
  }
  .col-sm-push-10 {
    left: 83.33333333%;
  }
  .col-sm-push-9 {
    left: 75%;
  }
  .col-sm-push-8 {
    left: 66.66666667%;
  }
  .col-sm-push-7 {
    left: 58.33333333%;
  }
  .col-sm-push-6 {
    left: 50%;
  }
  .col-sm-push-5 {
    left: 41.66666667%;
  }
  .col-sm-push-4 {
    left: 33.33333333%;
  }
  .col-sm-push-3 {
    left: 25%;
  }
  .col-sm-push-2 {
    left: 16.66666667%;
  }
  .col-sm-push-1 {
    left: 8.33333333%;
  }
  .col-sm-push-0 {
    left: auto;
  }
  .col-sm-offset-12 {
    margin-left: 100%;
  }
  .col-sm-offset-11 {
    margin-left: 91.66666667%;
  }
  .col-sm-offset-10 {
    margin-left: 83.33333333%;
  }
  .col-sm-offset-9 {
    margin-left: 75%;
  }
  .col-sm-offset-8 {
    margin-left: 66.66666667%;
  }
  .col-sm-offset-7 {
    margin-left: 58.33333333%;
  }
  .col-sm-offset-6 {
    margin-left: 50%;
  }
  .col-sm-offset-5 {
    margin-left: 41.66666667%;
  }
  .col-sm-offset-4 {
    margin-left: 33.33333333%;
  }
  .col-sm-offset-3 {
    margin-left: 25%;
  }
  .col-sm-offset-2 {
    margin-left: 16.66666667%;
  }
  .col-sm-offset-1 {
    margin-left: 8.33333333%;
  }
  .col-sm-offset-0 {
    margin-left: 0%;
  }
  .visible-xs {
    display: none !important;
  }
  .hidden-xs {
    display: block !important;
  }
  table.hidden-xs {
    display: table;
  }
  tr.hidden-xs {
    display: table-row !important;
  }
  th.hidden-xs,
  td.hidden-xs {
    display: table-cell !important;
  }
  .hidden-xs.hidden-print {
    display: none !important;
  }
  .hidden-sm {
    display: none !important;
  }
  .visible-sm {
    display: block !important;
  }
  table.visible-sm {
    display: table;
  }
  tr.visible-sm {
    display: table-row !important;
  }
  th.visible-sm,
  td.visible-sm {
    display: table-cell !important;
  }
}
```

The Columns are stacked below one by one like:

```
HI 
CSS
HI 
CSS
HI 
CSS
```

But I want To Get it Like:

```
HI CSS
HI CSS
HI CSS
```

Can Anyone Help Me on this Please.

[This is the preview i am getting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pC6Nx.png)

Comment: Seems to be working fine. Can you add some snapshots

Comment: As you have defined your css to work with media of print only it will be different in screen. To check it, you can take the print of it and see the result. or remove `@media print` and see if it gives the desired output.

Comment: Or you can emulate media print. In Chrome it's located at 'Developer Tools' (F12) --> *three dots top right* --> 'More tools' --> 'Rendering settings' --> [x] 'Emulate media'

Comment: Most likely the printed page width is less than the `col-sm-` breakpoint. Have you tried using `col-xs-` in your print.css instead?

Comment: i changed it didnt work

Comment: pugazh i added a snap

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use the CSS Media Query Print.

You can find the documentation here http://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_mediaqueries.asp

```
@media print {
   …
}
```